# Use VBA to copy an image from headers/footers of one sheet to another

Tags: excel, page-setup, vba

I need to write a VBA code to copy a company logo in the headers/footers of one excel sheet to another sheet in another workbook. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

Excel has a handy Record Macro function.

You can initiate that, Copy the footer over, then stop the recording.

Then, review the code, and it should pretty much show you how to do it.

Comment: This approach is hugely valuable for any office automation work.  It's the "secret API documentation" that makes the Office COM APIs discoverable, at least in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working in anything older than Excel 2007 then it doesn't sound like this is possible without using the original graphic file (e.g. JPG, GIF etc):

> Normally, you can copy and paste the
>   headers and footers from one worksheet
>   to another by selecting the worksheets
>   and then using the Header or Footer
>   dialog boxes (click Custom Header or
>   Custom Footer on the Header/Footer tab
>   of the Page Setup dialog box).
>   However, if the original headers and
>   footers contain graphics, the graphics
>   will not propagate to the other
>   worksheets. The only way to work with
>   pictures in headers or footers for
>   multiple worksheets is to select all
>   the worksheets, and then insert a
>   graphic by using the Insert Picture
>   dialog box (click the Insert Picture
>   button), or format the graphic by
>   using the Format Picture dialog box
>   (click the Format Picture button). The
>   original graphic file is needed for
>   this procedure.
>
> [source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HA010346411033.aspx)

It may be possible in Excel 2007 - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd627338.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

One workaround is to copy the **original** worksheet to the **new** workbook:

```
   ' macro on the source workbook
    Sheets("Sheet1").Move After:=Workbooks("Book2").Sheets(3)
```

When you do this, you get a worksheet in the destination workbook with all the features of the original, including footers and headers, you can then copy all the content you want into the new worksheet